# Lots of ideas, but don't want to tell stories

Tags: creative-writing

I sometimes have ideas for what I think might be compelling stories - most would fall in the category of fantasy/science fiction; however, I realise that I have no real interest in telling stories. I write good prose and explain well, but I tend to write about technical matters, generally speaking, and if I set out to write a story, I quickly get bored and start thinking about the logical/technical/scientific aspects instead. Is there a 'market' for story ideas? I don't mean in a commercial sense, all I'd want is a kind mention in the forewords or something, but something like a forum where I can offload my ideas and the real writers could browse around and discuss?

Comment: I'm going to try and word this in a non-harsh way, but to speak frankly, ideas are worthless without execution. I can say I have good ideas all I want, but no one cares about my ideas until I write them down, put effort into them, structure them, and make them interesting and compelling. Your question is the equivalent of saying, "I don't want to do the work of seeing my ideas through, I just want to be an ideas man and have other people flesh them out for me." But you don't get anywhere that way. You can't "farm it out" - you have to put in the work if you want to succeed.

Comment: @Sciborg I wonder what the harsh way, you had in mind would sound like? But you misunderstand my intention - I am just after a plain answer, not a lecture about why I'm too lazy or whatever. There seems to have been at least one person who thought it was an interesting question, so perhaps it isn't such a bad question; after all, there are questions here asking about inspiration, so maybe an 'ideas exchange' is relevant?

Comment: It wasn't the concept of sharing ideas and inspiration I had taken umbrage with, it was the way you had been asking for "a forum where I can offload my ideas and the real writers could browse around and discuss." I apologize if I misinterpreted that, but it came across like you were only interested in farming out your ideas for credit, which I view as slightly misguided and taking advantage of creative people. However, if you had meant it as only giving small writing prompts and ideas for fun, then that is fine and I am sorry for the misinterpretation.

Comment: No worries - although, what I had in mind was something more than short prompts, probably more like and outline of a sketch. I'm autistic, and to me dialogue consists in giving concise answers to concrete questions; I'm not into smalltalk (except as a programming language), and I would substitute a storyline with a logical exploration of the concepts involved. But I do get these radical ideas, like what if the Antichrist is in fact Jesus in his second coming, and he's come to clean out the fundamental corruption that is religion? (sorry, no offence meant)

Comment: As someone who also has lots of ideas for things I have no interest making, one thing I’ve learned is that most ideas when actually made into something stink. But it’s really hard to know that until you try to make them into something. Which is why ideas by themselves don’t have much value. Probably best to view them as rocks that may possibly maybe contain a fleck of gold than as gold nuggets. Most will stink. A few will be ok. Once in a rare while one will be a gem (or rather will contain a gem to be extracted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of to what you're describing is writing prompts. They're short (maybe 40-50 words) and provide the seed of an idea, essentially just a premise that a writer can take as a starting point to create a story from.

For examples of what I mean (and potentially even a place to post your own) there's a SubReddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/)

Comment: Yes, could be. I've never been on reddit, actually. Are the any limits to how much one can write in one post?

Comment: A prompt is typically short. A sentence, maybe two. Don't expect people to read a 20 page world building document, regardless of quality.

Comment: @AnnaA.Fitzgerald At least, [not until *after* there are successful novels set in the world...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion)